# Adding stones or bricks to the Bais Hamikdash

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, beis-hamikdash

As a child I was told, and now my children are being told, that when they do a Mitzva a brick gets added to the Bais Hamikdash. As pointed out by DoubleAA, the [Rambam](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=8&hilchos=41&perek=1&halocha=8&hilite=) says that it is preferable to build the Bais Hamikdash with stones. As pointed out by Isaac Moses, [here's an example](http://crownheights.info/chabad-news/49068/worlds-largest-mosaic-mitzvah-menorah-in-chicago/) of this concept presented by a teacher of children: "*Rabbi Yitzchok Wolf, the dean of Cheder Lubavitch*". Is there an earlier source that for each Mitzva either a stone or brick gets added to the building of the third temple?

Comment: I don't think it was meant to be anything more than than a pretty metaphor for misswoth bringing us closer to moshiah. Are you looking for a source that this is true, or are you looking for an example of this metaphor being used earlier than recent history? Source and origin of metaphor aren't strictly the same thing.

Comment: I believe that this was stated by R. M. M. Schneerson. I think this is the source.

Comment: @ShamanSTK: I am both looking for a reliable source that has said such, and also what is the earliest source to have said such.

Comment: @mevaqesh: I find your contention that it was stated by R. M. M. Schneerson interesting. As I have been unable to find any such saying in Likutei Sichos or any other works by him.

Comment: I have often heard it said using stones instead of bricks.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.jerusalemchai.org/AVeditor/repository/images/Articles/Weekly%20Newsletter/Weekly-Newsletter-02-12-2016.pdf) (fn. 2) mention sefer Pnei Shabbat, page 297 who quotes this idea from the Zera ha-Kodesh (which unfortunately I haven't been able to see it for myself). However, I would say that (whether the source is this or that), this notion (perhaps) may be derived from Gemora ([Berachos 6b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95_%D7%91)) which mention that whoever fullfil the mitzvah of gladdening the bride and groom is as if he/she rebuilt one of the חורבות ירושלים:

> וא"ר חלבו אמר רב הונא כל הנהנה מסעודת חתן ואינו משמחו עובר בחמשה קולות
>   שנאמר (ירמיהו לג, יא) קול ששון וקול שמחה קול חתן וקול כלה קול אומרים
>   הודו את ה' צבאות **ואם משמחו מה שכרו** אמר רבי יהושע בן לוי זוכה לתורה
>   שנתנה בחמשה קולות שנאמר (שמות יט, טז) ויהי ביום השלישי בהיות הבקר ויהי
>   קולות וברקים וענן כבד על ההר וקול שופר וגו' ויהי קול השופר וגו'
>   והאלהים יעננו בקול. איני והא כתיב (שמות כ, יד) וכל העם רואים את הקולת
>   אותן קולות דקודם מתן תורה הוו רבי אבהו אמר כאילו הקריב תודה שנאמר
>   (ירמיהו לג, יא) מביאים תודה בית ה' רב נחמן בר יצחק אמר **כאילו בנה אחת
>   מחורבות ירושלים**

Another source, ([Midrash Tanhuma, Tzav 14](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/tanhuma/25.htm)) says that the study of the structures of the Temple is as if one rebuilds them:

> אמר לו הקדוש ברוך ליחזקאל: ובשביל שבני נתונים בגולה, יהא בנין ביתי
>   בטל?! אמר לו הקדוש ברוך הוא, גדול קרייתה בתורה כבנינה. לך אמור להם,
>   ויתעסקו לקרות צורת הבית בתורה. ובשכר קרייתה שיתעסקו לקרות בה, אני מעלה
>   עליהם כאלו הם עוסקין בבניין הבית.

The view that "each mitzva adds stones to the Bais Hamikdash" seems to be an interpretation extended to all mitzvos.

Comment: I wonder if the OP wanted sources that are specific to the *stones*, not that it's "as if one built it".